# Compile error on "using System.Data;"

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2013

I am a bloody beginner, trying to get a function to work which I picked-up from the web. It calculates the SHA2-256 encryption for SQL Server 2008.

I got Visual Studio Community Edition installed, pasted the code into the class window. Now I get the blue squiggles indicating that some assemblies are not found, e.g.:

```
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;
```

When I BUILD the class library, I receive the message:

> error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Data' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Checked all over the Internet, but still have not figured out how to get this repaired.

Comment: **are** you missing an assembly reference?

Comment: In fact, do you know what an "assembly reference" is? As a beginner, it's a very good ideal to go learn any terms you don't know. That way, you'll know them.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: John, thanks for bringing my text into proper form!

Answer (score 1):

In your project in Solution Explorer, expand the References node and check if System.Data is in the list.

If not right click > Add Reference and add System.Data

Hope that helps

Comment: I did that before, got to a screen titled "Reference Manager - Encryption" where "Encryption" is the name of my project. Entered "system.data" into the search box, got "No items found".

Comment: Are you looking in the tab called "Assemblies"? That's where `System.Data` is located

Comment: In Reference Manager, select Assemblies > Framework, then search?

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a reference to the `System.Data` assembly in order to be able to use those namespaces.  Right-click on the project, click `Add`, and click `Reference...`.  From the list, select `System.Data`.

[image: Add Reference]

[image: System.Data]